# How to maintain the same session using a cookie jar in Go

Tags: go, request, session-cookies, go-http

I am wondering how I can maintain the same session using a cookie jar in Go

I have done this in JS using this method:

```
const cookieJar = request.jar();

request({
    headers: {
    //headers here
    },
    url: url,
    jar: cookieJar
    method: 'GET'
```

I am wondering if there is an euqivalent of the above code for Go. Thanks!

Comment: Try [net/http/cookiejar](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/)

Comment: yes, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cat try something like this:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8080/", nil)
if err != nil { // ... }

jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
if err != nil { // ... }

client := &http.Client{Jar: jar}

res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil { // ... }
```